# How to close Activity after clicking Progress Dialog Button

Tags: java, android

That's my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setTitle("Titel");
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Activity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.decline), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // handle accepting
        }
    });
alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

My problem is that the Activity doesn't close when clicking Decline.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As per the given snippet your Positive and Negative Buttons are swapped, aren't they? Also if you want to finish an Activity, if you are inside an Activity just finish() method would do.

Comment: I don't see they're swapped. Can you help me?

Comment: Also, you need to use your activity name, such as MyActivity.this.finish(), and not Activity.this.finish()

Comment: That doesn't work. Only the progress dialog is closing...

Comment: I think it is not needed here, as per this snippet the Alert Dialog is opened inside an Activity.

Comment: Where is the Progress Dialog? Show some code.

Comment: I wonder if you are inside an Activity or a Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have switched the labelling of the buttons.

```
                                        //was R.string.accept 
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.decline), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Activity.this.finish();
    }
});
                                  //was R.string.decline
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        // handle accepting
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

    }
});
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.decline), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Activity.this.finish();
    }
});
alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```